# Check bluetooth state in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios6, iphone-privateapi

I have an application (I am not going to submit this app to apple app store) using which I want to check  whether bluetooth is turned on. If it is turned on then I have to display an alert.

```
    - (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{
  switch (central.state) {
    case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:{
      //alert view
      break;
    }
  }
```

And in `viewdidload` I did like this

```
  CBCentralManager * manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
```

but this is not working in ipad2 with ios 5.1.

> the problem is `central.state` is always null.

I want the same scenario to work from ios 3.0 to ios 6 beta. Is there any common code for checking bluetooth state.

Any possible code is welcome, even code with private api.

Answer (score 3):

`CBCentralManager` is for using Bluetooth Smart (the Low Energy part in Bluetooth 4.0). This is a new technology only recently introduced in iOS / OS X devices. Current support is in iPhone 4s and the new iPad. The iPad 2 does NOT have support for this technology. Also the `CBCentralManager` is only available from iOS 5 and up.

If you want to check traditional Bluetooth state you will have to find another way to do that.

In your case `central.state` should actually equal `CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported`.

Comment: Thanks man. you made it clear. Do u have any solution i.e, any code to detect bluetooth state which works for all device and os.

Comment: Not that I know of. But I only work against public API's, so not really my area of expertise.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at the `BluetoothManager` API.  The **BluetoothManager.framework** is the *private* framework that this API lives in.  You can link to it from within your Xcode project, or use `dlopen` to open it (`"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager"`) dynamically.

The important calls would be

```objc
- (BOOL)powered;
- (BOOL)enabled;
- (BOOL)setPowered:(BOOL)arg1;
- (BOOL)setEnabled:(BOOL)arg1;
```

To get an instance of the `BluetoothManager`, use this:

```objc
BluetoothManager* mgr = [BluetoothManager sharedInstance];
```

Answer (score 1):

I´m also not getting CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported on an iPhone 4 running iOS7. I opened a bug ticket with Apple.

http://openradar.appspot.com/15564675 is the radar

and https://github.com/deadfalkon/btLeState the repository

Comment: The feature is supported on 4S and up only: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#Features