# How can I know if my device's blue tooth is power on?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I just need to get my ios device's bluetooth state.

Is there somebody know the API,I have search for the apple.com but didn't found sth, also I know I can use the `CoreBluetooth`,but it can just be used when `IOS6` later,so what about `IOS5`?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173344/check-bluetooth-state-in-ios
it might help u.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CBCentralManager` for that, the property `state` has these values:

```
typedef enum {
   CBCentralManagerStateUnknown = 0,
   CBCentralManagerStateResetting,
   CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported,
   CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized,
   CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff,
   CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn,
}
```

Find all the documentation here:

[CBCentralManager Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/translated_content/CBCentralManager.html)

Comment: Thank you so much~But I init the class in my (viewDidLoad) function,I just want to get the state when I init it,bue I get 0(CBCentralManagerStateUnknown, CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn is expected.) And also I don't want a alert like that "Turn on Bluetooth to Allow "***" to Connect to Accessories."Also I have to realize the delegate to get the correct state,ok,this is acceptable.But I really don't need the alert. How can I change this?@Antonio MG